# Using Environment Variables for MsDeploy package

Tags: environment-variables, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm trying to setup something with WebDeploy that will allow configuration of Environment Variables to set the "parameters.xml" parameters in a web deploy package.

From what I've read so far, this should be possible, but I've not had any success yet.

Essentially, it's TeamCity that I'm using to do it, but the concept is beyond a usage in TeamCity.

I'm using the generated cmd that you get from using the /t:Package target.

So my question is, is this possible? or is there another solution for iterating the teamcity variables and updating the SetParameters.xml (rather than manually coding an XML Poke foreach, or using /property syntax on the raw MsDeploy.exe).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference environment variables from the command line when you run the msdeploy command.  I don't have experience with TeamCity but I suspect you give it a msdeploy.exe command to run.

This post gives more details - http://evolutionarydeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/05/specifying-environment-variables-at.html